# pyspark dataframe Column with Decimal(38,10) with scientific notation how to find regex

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, rlike

I am using below line to check for numbers

```
when(df[COL_VALUE_DEC].rlike("^[0-9.]+$"), 1)
```

and datatype of column COL_VALUE_DEC is DECIMAL(38,10)

When the value is 0 in this column, pyspark is returning it as 0E-10 and thus it is not matching the regex.

I tried below trick with format_number but then the actual numbers are not getting matched.

```
when(format_number(df[COL_VALUE_DEC],2).rlike("^[0-9.]+$"), 1)
```

How do I solve this problem?

0E-10

0.00

10.13

10

All above should be treated as 1 in my condition.

Comment: why would you use regex to check a non-string column? just use `isinstance`